# gem installation with Ruby2 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I'm trying to install rails, but before I need to install devkit correctly.
So I'm making the normal procedure but I don't understand what's wrong. I'm using ruby 2 x64, and I tried with the DevKit x32 and x64. this is with the devkit x64. What can be wrong in here..? Thank You.

```
c:\DevKit>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
/json-1.8.0/lib/C/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x64-msvcrt/json/ext
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/C/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x64-msvcrt/json/ext'
: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-
1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ex
t/generator/gem_make.out
```

NOTE: Before I installed with "ruby dk.rb install -f" in both x32 and x64 cases.

EDIT: For who is attempting to reply about the ruby dk.rb etc. procedure, I've done multiple times this:

c:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init 
Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

c:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb review 
Based upon the settings in the 'config.yml' file generated
from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations,
DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies
when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:/Ruby200-x64

c:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install -f 
[WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200-x64' 
[WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'

Comment: Are you running as an administrator?

Comment: yes, on the cmd is written: Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I have also windows with installed java,jdk

I tried

```
 ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\rajarshid>gem install json --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.8.0
Parsing documentation for json-1.8.0
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/json/ext/generator.so, skipping
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/json/ext/parser.so, skipping
Installing ri documentation for json-1.8.0
Done installing documentation for json (2 sec).
1 gem installed
```

**Please check whether dev kit install properly or not**

```
ruby dk.rb review
```

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: you probably have the x86 version, I see.. Anyway as I wrote, I did everything required in that page, 3 or 4 times with different things, and nothing worked, and I widely searched in the internet what can be the cause.